# Does Vim scrolling performance degrade with vertically split windows?

Tags: vim

I've noticed this with my own set up, but I wanted to get confirmations from other people. Is there a way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, because in the presence of folding and needing to check which pane the cursor is in, there is a lot more to figure out.

As for ways do deal it, I make it a habit to use paging instead of scrolling (^F/^B for full page, ^U/^D for half page and z. to center on current line). At least for me, that is plenty fast even with triple vimdiffs open with plenty of folded lines.